# python virtualenv module not being imported

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtualenv

I have installed markdown using

```
pip install markdown
```

in a virutalenv project, running pip freeze shows me its installed.

but I get the following error when trying to use it

```
import markdown
ImportError: No module named markdown
```

the app is using google app engine. Adding it to app.yml as

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

gives me

```
raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: the library "markdown" is not supported
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import arbitrary libraries in to appengine, but not through `libraries` directive in app.yaml.

In addition, you can't run appengine under virtualenv.

You can use virtualenv/pip/easy_install to install libs and their dependancies, but you then need to link/copy the libraries into your project and manipulate your sys.path as appropriate.

Comment: I am running appengine under virtualenv, all I did was symlinking the sdk in my virtualenv folder - I already had the appengine systemwide installed

Comment: did you set up virtualenv with --no-site-packages ?  Which is normally what you would do, so as not to pollute the rest of your environment.

Comment: I think I did, don't really remember

Answer (score 0):

You can't import arbitrary third-party libraries into a GAE app. The official list of supported libraries is [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27), and it doesn't include markdown.